# Assigining last prority to multiple same event

Tags: javascript

I have a query which i am trying to figure out since a long time. Currently, i have 2 **dragleave** events, one is uploaded on server [do not have access] and the other one is written by me. Below is the code.

```
    $('#drag-and-drop-zone').bind('dragleave', function(){

     alert("hii");
    });
```

My requirement is that the dragleave which is uploaded on the server must be executed first and then my function should be executed after that. Currently, it is happening that my function is executed first and than the server one.

In-short, can any one please tell me how can i assign last priority to one event? i.e. my first should execute second and the server function should execute first

Comment: jQuery calls event handlers in the order that they were bound. So just make sure your own JS is included on the page *after* the JS that you can't change.

Comment: do you mean in the order, they are placed / written? Do not have an access to place the JS according to my wish. Can this be taken care with coding??

Comment: Probably. Please update your question to show how both pieces of JS are included on the page. Does the server code that you can't change bind the event handler in response to some other event, or...?